# Как обработать ошибку в discord.py, при неправильном заполнении типа данных?

Tags: python, discord.py

Например есть команда, и пользователю необходимо заполнить первое ее значение типом int. Но нужно сделать проверку, что если пользователь внесет в переменную не int, а например string, то вместо ошибки в консоль он получит сообщение что нужно вводить число, а не буквы. Помогите пожалуйста с кодом. Короче, проверка что если пользователь вместо значения int введет значение string, то выведется текст

```
@bot.command(aliases=['create', 'clan-create', 'create-clan'])
async def __create(ctx, status_private: int = None, *, name: str = None):
try:
    creator_role = False
    if status_private >= 2:
        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title = "Clans Create", description=f'Укажите тип вашего клана, где 0 - приватный, 1 - публичный. \n`>create [тип] [название]`', colour=discord.Color.from_rgb(240, 230, 140)))
    elif name == None:
        await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title = "Clans Create", description=f'Укажите название для вашего клана', colour=discord.Color.from_rgb(240, 230, 140)))
    else:

        if status_private == 0 or status_private == 1:
        
            cursor.execute('SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = {} AND server_id = {};'.format(ctx.author.id, ctx.guild.id))
            if cursor.fetchone()[0] < 1000:
                await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title = "Clans Create", description=f'**{ctx.author}**, у вас недостаточно средств для создания клана. Необходимо **1000** монет', colour=discord.Color.from_rgb(240, 230, 140)))
            
            else:

                cursor.execute("SELECT player_id FROM shop WHERE id = {};".format(ctx.guild.id))
                for row in cursor.fetchall():
                    if row[0] == ctx.author.id:
                        creator_role = True

                if creator_role == False:

                    role = await ctx.guild.create_role(name=name)
                    cursor.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = cash - {} WHERE id = {} AND server_id = {};".format(1000, ctx.author.id, ctx.guild.id))
                    connection.commit()
                    await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')
                    await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
                    
                    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO shop VALUES ({role.id}, {ctx.guild.id}, 200, 0, '{ctx.author.name}', {ctx.author.id}, 0, 0, 0, 0, {status_private});")
                    connection.commit()

                    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO cup_league VALUES ({role.id}, {ctx.guild.id}, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);")
                    connection.commit()

                    private_or_public = "None"

                    if status_private == 0:
                        private_or_public = "Приватный"
                    elif status_private == 1:
                        private_or_public = "Публичный"
                    
                    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title = "Clans Create", description=f'Клан под названием {role.mention} был создан. Создатель: {ctx.author.mention}. \n\nТекущий уровень позиции: **{role.position}** \n\nПо желанию можете попросить администрацию включить для вашего клана в настройках ролей пункт под названием "Отображать участников отдельно от других". \n\n Тип клана: **{private_or_public}**', colour=discord.Color.from_rgb(255, 215, 0)))

                else:
                    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title = "Clans Create", description=f'Вы можете быть создателем только одного клана.', colour=discord.Color.from_rgb(240, 230, 140)))
        else:
            await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title = "Clans Create", description=f'Измените тип клана, где 0 - приватный, 1 - публичный. \n`>create [тип] [название]`', colour=discord.Color.from_rgb(240, 230, 140)))

except:
    emb = discord.Embed(title = "Ошибка", description = "Произошла ошибка, ознакомьтесь с причинами ниже: \n\n `1.` Убедитесь, что вы прописываете команду правильно: `>create [тип клана, 0 - приватный, 1 - публичный] [Название]` \n\n `2.` Проверьте, что бы у бота были включены права: `Управлять ролями, Упоминание ролей` \n `3.` Если все вышеперечисленные параметры верны, воспользуйтесь сервером поддержки.", colour=discord.Color.from_rgb(205, 92, 92))
    await ctx.send(embed=emb)
```

Answer (score 0):

использовать конструкцию `try` `catch`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Что ж Никитка, давай тебе поможем :)
Добавь error handler к твоей команде:

```py
@__create.error
async def clan_create_error(ctx, error):
    # обработать ошибку error
```